# Table inside Header

Tags: tables, fancyhdr

I'm trying to create table inside Hearder to looks like this :

**Output** 
[image]

but with my following

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,top=0.5in,headheight=5\baselineskip,headsep=1\baselineskip,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}


%create table =============================================================================================================================
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\definecolor{MatlabCellColour}{RGB}{252,251,220}
\newcolumntype{A}[2]{%
    >{\minipage{\dimexpr#1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-#2\arrayrulewidth\relax}\vspace\tabcolsep}%
    c<{\vspace\tabcolsep\endminipage}}


\newenvironment{Table}[4]{%
    \longtable{%
        |A{#1}{1.5}% for figure
        |>{\centering$\displaystyle}A{#2}{1}<{$}% for inline equation
        |>{\correction{-1}\strut\[}A{#3}{1}<{\]\strut}% for displayed equation
        |>{\centering}A{#4}{1.5}% for text
        |}\hline\ignorespaces}{%
    \endlongtable\ignorespacesafterend}


%% some invisible "struts" to help define the structures and row heights.
%% set up and width for the tabularx environment to expand and fit to.
\newlength{\headerwidth}
\setlength{\headerwidth}{\textwidth}
\newsavebox{\myheader}

\begin{lrbox}{\myheader}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\headerwidth}
        \noindent

\longtable{|A{0.2}{1.5}|A{0.2}{1.5}||A{0.2}{1.5}|A{0.2}{1.5}|}\arrayrulecolor{green}\hline\hline 
\rowcolor{MatlabCellColour} \multicolumn{1}{|A{0.3}{1}|}{\centering Author }& \multicolumn{3}{|A{0.7}{1}|}{ \centering Universität der Mathematik Department of Mathematics }\tabularnewline\hline\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|A{0.2}{1}|}{   \textbf{Page \thepage \ of \ \pageref{LastPage} } } & \multicolumn{1}{|A{0.2}{1}|}{\centering Subject } & \multicolumn{1}{|A{0.2}{1}|}{ \centering Year } & \multicolumn{1}{|A{0.3}{1}|}{\centering Mathematics competitions }\tabularnewline\hline 
\endlongtable
    \vspace{-0.5ex}\par
    \bfseries
    Time: 120 Min \hspace*{\fill} 
    Date:        \hspace*{\fill}
    Marks:40
        \bigskip
    \end{minipage}
        \bigskip
\end{lrbox}

%% Setting up the header
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\lhead{}
\chead{\usebox{\myheader}}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}



\begin{document}
\noindent

\longtable{|A{0.2}{1.5}|A{0.2}{1.5}||A{0.2}{1.5}|A{0.2}{1.5}|}\arrayrulecolor{green}\hline\hline 
\rowcolor{MatlabCellColour} \multicolumn{1}{|A{0.3}{1}|}{\centering Author }& \multicolumn{3}{|A{0.7}{1}|}{ \centering Universität der Mathematik Department of Mathematics }\tabularnewline\hline\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{|A{0.2}{1}|}{   \textbf{Page \thepage \ of \ \pageref{LastPage} } } & \multicolumn{1}{|A{0.2}{1}|}{\centering Subject } & \multicolumn{1}{|A{0.2}{1}|}{ \centering Year } & \multicolumn{1}{|A{0.3}{1}|}{\centering Mathematics competitions }\tabularnewline\hline 
\endlongtable
 \vspace{-0.5ex}\par
    \bfseries
    Time: 120 Min \hspace*{\fill} 
    Date:        \hspace*{\fill}
    Marks:40
\bigskip

\lipsum[1]
\newpage 
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

I got this

**Output**
[image]

- Could anyone offer any solutions or suggestions please?

Comment: What's the reason for `longtable` in the header? I see none.

Comment: i used it to let me write long equation inside cell if i want to

Comment: Your headheight is probably too low and you get a warning/information in the log-file.

Comment: @Educ That has *nothing* to do with `longtable`.

Comment: @egreg i used it to do it for  that purpose but okay i got it

Comment: @Educ `tabular` is good as well; `longtable` is for tables split across pages.

Comment: @egreg  ok.i see now the difference (long ) Thank you so with tabular gonna fix the problem ?

Comment: @Johannes_B i notice that it told me that i have to make  it at least 92.16945pt.

Comment: Try not to load the same package multiple times, e.g. `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`

Comment: @samcarter i did but stil no color in table plus no lastpage

Comment: Is that tabular supossed to appear on every page?

Comment: @Johannes_B  yes as Header

Answer (score 4):

Another code using `tabulary` this time, but the main idea is the same  "keep it simple" principle.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,top=0.5in,headheight=7\baselineskip,
headsep=1.5\baselineskip,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\chead{
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\tabcolsep3em
\arrayrulecolor{green!70!black}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|C|C|C|C|}
\hline\rowcolor{yellow!15} 
Author & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{%
Universität der Mathematik Department of Mathematics}\\
\hline\bfseries 
Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage} &  
Subject & 
Year & 
Mathematics competitions\\
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\linebreak\vskip2ex\bfseries
Time: 120 Min \hfill Date: \hfill Marks: 40}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: there is just one problem  if i enlarge font size table will get out of page width (Table out of the margin)

Comment: @Educ Then reduce  `\tabcolsep` accordingly. May be you will need modify also `\arraystretch` and `geometry`  options  `headheight` and `headsep`. Add also the `showframe` option to check where is  the top margin with your modifications.

Answer (score 3):

The following code gives almost exactly what you show in the first    picture.
Please note, that no savevox is used. A savebox really is like taking a photo, and printing that photo on every use of the box. That said, references won't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,top=0.5in,headheight=5\baselineskip,headsep=1\baselineskip,includehead,
%showframe
]{geometry}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{MatlabCellColour}{RGB}{252,251,220}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{%
    \arrayrulecolor{green!70!black}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \renewcommand{\arrayrulewidth}{.6pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{MatlabCellColour}Author & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Universit\"at der Mathematik Department of Mathematics }\\
        \hline
        \bfseries Page \thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage}&Subject&Year&Other text\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \bigbreak
    \bfseries
    Time: 120 Min \hspace*{\fill} 
    Date:        \hspace*{\fill}
    Marks: 40
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Danke vielmals but could you explain the idea of your work please

Comment: There really isn't much to explain. This is a very simple tabular (with hideous colors that i would avoid). All that is just stuffed into the header. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I just started to read it if i stuck i will let you know thank you