# How do I create a footer containing a 2 x 5 table?

Tags: tables, header-footer, templates

Good Morning everyone (UTC+2),

I need to write a few documents for work. All of them with the same layout. They gave me a ms word-template, but I would like to write them with latex because I want to practice it.

They have this weird footer layout, which is not pretty at all, but what can I do. It has to be like that. Here is a screenshot of the footer.
[image: ms word-template footer]

I managed to create a multiline footer (see code below) in latex that would contain all the necessary information, but it has to be that exact footer. I just cannot figure out how to put a table like that in the footer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[mongolian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\setlength{\headheight}{40pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyfoot[L]{Document-Version: \\ XXXXXXX-YY \\ \ \\ CREATED: XX.YY.ZZZZ \\} 
\fancyfoot[R]{----- \\ VN \\ \  \\ Page \thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{VN}
\begin{document}
....
\end{document}
```

I found [this](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11507) link, but it did not really help me much. At least I couldnt figure out how to manipulate the code so it would look like it does in the screenshot. I am pretty new to latex, but it has been a few hours now that I spent trying. So if anyone has an idea or a hint they wanna share with me, please feel free to to so. Thanks a lot

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please extend your code snippet to small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document}` help us to help you! see, if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284825/table-inside-header can help you.

Comment: @Zarko Done! I willt take a look at the link right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need `fancyhdr` for any header you can as well don't use `fancyhdr` and instead redefine `\@oddfoot` yourself.

The following does so and uses `tabularx` for a full-width table. The first two cells are enlarged and the others are reduced in size, to make the longer "Document-Version" and possible date fit. You might adjust those enlargements, only make sure that the total of the numbers used prior to `\hsize` match the number of columns (so 6 here). No number counts as a 1.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\month=11 % November has the longest name (dealing with edge cases for size)

\newcommand*\clineReveal
  {%
    \noalign{\vskip\arrayrulewidth}%
  }

\makeatletter
\def\@oddfoot
  {%
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}
      {
        |*2{>{\hsize=1.3\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X|}
        *4{>{\hsize=.85\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X|}
      }
      \hline
      Document-Version & Date & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots & Page \thepage \\
      \cline{1-5}\clineReveal
      xxxxx-zz & \today & V.N. & V.N. & V.N. & of \pageref{LastPage}\\
      \hline
    \end{tabularx}%
  }
\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
\makeatother

\usepackage{duckuments}% for dummy content

\begin{document}
\duckument
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Explanations:

`\@oddfoot` is the macro which is used by the standard classes to typeset the footer (along with `\@evenfoot` in `twoside` documents).

`tabularx` is a table-like environment which sets a table to a specified width. The `X` type column is a column of flexible width (it gets big enough that the table spans the requested width, if multiple `X` columns are specified the space is split evenly).

The `>{...}` in the preamble of `tabularx` is code to be inserted at the start of each cell of that column. `\hsize=1.3\hsize` enlarges the column by 30%. `\linewidth=\hsize` also sets `\linewidth` to the specified size. Altogether `>{\hsize=<num>\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X` is the recommended way to not evenly split the available space in the `tabularx` documentation.

I've added `\clineReveal` because by default a `\cline` does not take up vertical space (which would be inconsistent with an ordinary `\hline`), `\clineReveal` adds the vertical space a `\hline` would take.

And I use the `lastpage` package to get the total number of pages which is defined on second run and can be print with `\pageref{LastPage}`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I don't completely understand it yet. Still learning... I will definitly look into it and find out how it works exactly!

Comment: @Geddi I've added some explanations. Is that enough, or do you not understand other things?

Comment: So far so good thanks a lot. How do I adjust the footer height. It seems to take up a lot of space arround the table.

Comment: @Geddi since you use `geometry` you can take a look in its [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry), the keys should be something with `foot` in their names. But be aware that some space is good so that it is easier to distinguish from content. It's a very common mistake to think that too much space is lost in margins etc. (Though I know that you want to match a Word template).