# One table in ALL pages

Tags: tables

I need to place a table at the begining of ALL pages of a document. This is must as it will contain some technical data about a proyect and it should be repeated in all pages except index and portrait.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284825/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table inside Header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284825/table-inside-header)

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout the [fancyhdr](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package. It adds custom headers and footers for a document. I cannot provide an example since you are not giving information about your required table.

I hope this helps.